# How to generate JSON from other JSON files, based on commonly shared members?

Tags: python

I have a number of JSON files:

```
json_files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']
```

Their contents:

```
# file1.json
{
    "foo": ["bar", "baz"],
    "hello": ["wonderful", "world"]
}

# file2.json
{
    "foo": ["bar", "xxx", "baz"],
    "hello": ["world"]
}

# file3.json
{
    "foo": ["bar", "boo"],
    "hello": ["cruel", "world"]
}
```

Using Python, I'd like to analyze these files and output a new JSON file which will only contain the commonly shared key/values:

```
# Generated JSON
{
    "foo": ["bar"],
    "hello": ["world"]
}
```

How can this be achieved?
This is what I have so far:

```
import json


def read_json(filename):
    """Read JSON, return dict"""
    with open(filename, 'r') as data_file:
        return json.load(data_file)


def write_json(dictionary, filename):
    """Write dictionary to JSON"""
    with open(filename, 'w') as data_file:
        json.dump(dictionary, data_file, indent=4)


def compare(dicts):
    """Generate JSON with commonly shared members"""

    <LOOP HERE>

    return common_members


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1 = read_json('file1.json')
    f2 = read_json('file2.json')
    f3 = read_json('file3.json')

    dicts = [f1, f2, f3]
    common_members = compare(dicts)
    write_json(common_members, 'common_members.json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a flat structure (no arbitrary nesting), find the key intersection of the dictionaries, and then iterate over it, finding the item intersection for each common key.

```
from functools import reduce

def compare(dicts):
    common_members = {}
    common_keys = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, map(dict.keys, dicts))
    for k in common_keys:
        common_members[k] = list(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [set(d[k]) 
                                                        for d in dicts]))

    return common_members
```